# How to handle cordova onCordovaInfoReady if the same is used in two different plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova device plugin for getting the device data.
I just copied the same and only edited the file names, namespaces along with plugin ID.

Plugin is successfully imported and available in android folder after adding platforms.
Now, when I run the app. log says "deviceready has not fired after5 seconds ... onCordovaInfoReady is not fired etc."
This happens only after installing the edited plugin.
Basically, am trying to achieve some encryption methodology from the new plugin.

Now since both the calling js i.e. device and the duplicate which I created has onCordovaInfoready can cause problem ?

Plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the plugin id, then you need to make the changes in all references.

or

Just change the code of the copied plugin and install the newly created plugin locally it will install a fresh copy of new plugin in all respective folders and files like android.json, plugins folder , res/xml/config.xml etc.

Comment: If i use both the plugin together,it throws the above error.But when used independently, works fine ! Any idea ?